# two network cards routing

Tags: macos, routes

i have two ethernet cards in my Mac en0 connected to a router using DHCP and connected to the internet and en1 connected to a second router to the private wireless network dedicated to file sharing and gaming

en0: DHCP assigned
address: 192.168.1.226
mask: 255.255.255.0
gw: 192.168.1.1

en1: manual
address: 10.168.60.65
mask: 255.255.255.192
gw: 10.168.60.65

on the PC i simply add a route 10.0.0.0 mask 255.0.0.0 10.168.60.65 -p
but doing similar thing on mac just does not work (route -n add 10.0.0.0/8 10.168.60.65)
tis is a big network and i need to be able to connect to many different ranges (10.5.0.0, 10.4.0.0, 10.111.0.0, and so on)

traceroute to anything inside 10.168.0.0 range always shows that it tries to go through 192.168. gw

how should i configure this Mac?

thx

Answer (score 2):

Try the following:

sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 -interface en0
or
sudo route add -net 10.0.0.0/8 -interface en1
depending on which one you need enabled.

Comment: thx EmkoOne. i've found that there was an old persistent route i've added some time a go also trying to solve this same problem but it was, wrong. Deleted it and added `code`sudo route -nv add -net 10.0.0.0/8 10.168.60.65. Works good now :)